# merging rows in csv where row[0] is a duplicate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file that has student_id,guardian_email,guardian_first_name,guardian_last_name

In many cases, the student has a mom and dad with info, so the student has more than one row in the csv file.

For example the original csv would look like this:

```
student_id,guardian_email,guardian_first_name,guardian_last_name
12345,momemail@google.com,Jane,Doe
12345,dademail@google.com,John,Doe
98765,coollady@yahoo.com,Mary,Poppins
99999,soccermom@bing.net,Laura,Croft
99999,blackbelt@karate.com,Chuck,Norris
```

using python, I want it to output this:

```
student_id,guardian_email,guardian_first_name,guardian_last_name,guardian_email2,guardian_first_name2,guardian_last_name2
12345,momemail@google.com,Jane,Doe,dademail@google.com,John,Doe
98765,coollady@yahoo.com,Mary,Poppins,,,
99999,soccermom@bing.net,Laura,Croft,blackbelt@karate.com,Chuck,Norris
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `groupby()`+`cumcount()` to track position and then `pivot()`:

```
df['s']=df.groupby('student_id').cumcount()+1
df=df.pivot('student_id','s',['guardian_email','guardian_first_name','guardian_last_name'])
df.columns=[f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in df.columns]
df=df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```

**OR**

use `groupby()`+`cumcount()` to track position and then `unstack()`

```
df=df.assign(s=df.groupby('student_id').cumcount()+1).set_index(['student_id','s']).unstack()
df.columns=[f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in df.columns]
df=df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your expected output

Update:

try:

```
def guardianemailfinal():
    path=r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\pythonscripts\Major-Clarity\files\guardian_email.csv'
    df=pd.read_csv(path,sep=',')
    df['s']=df.groupby('student_id').cumcount()+1
    df=df.pivot('student_id','s',['guardian_email','guardian_first_name','guardian_last_name'])
    df.columns=[f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in df.columns]
    df=df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
    df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\pythonscripts\Major-Clarity\files\output.csv',index=False,sep=',')
    return df

#Finally call the function:
df=guardianemailfinal()
```

**Note:** Now If you print `df` you will get the modified dataframe and check your **path** then you will get `'output.csv'` file

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I tried implementing this and I am getting an error:  UnboundLocalError: df['s']=df.groupby('student_id').cumcount()+1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment.........   Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JosephSanders Sir you are getting this error in both of the methods? or are you using the above methods inside the function?

Comment: Im using the first example(pivot) inside the function that creates the csv file

Comment: @JosephSanders so that's the reason sir for that use global or pass parameter to your function pls see this  [unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Comment: def guardianemailfinal():
    global df
    with open(r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\pythonscripts\Major-Clarity\files\guardian_email.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')

        df['s']=df.groupby('student_id').cumcount()+1
        df=df.pivot('student_id','s',['guardian_email','guardian_first_name','guardian_last_name'])
        df.columns=[f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in df.columns]
        df=df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
        print (df)

Comment: the above is what I have, I had to create a new function because it was erasing the data from the csv in the other function.... when I put global df at the beginning of the function it now says df is not defined. Apparantly I am setting this entire function up wrong. All i want to do is read the csv file, and then output either into a new csv or into the same csv, the info as originally shown and I am failing miserably here

Comment: @JosephSanders sir updated answer...kindly check if it works for you or not!

Comment: thanks for your help thus far. I did that and this time I get no errors, but the csv file does not get updated with anything at all. I used print(df) and what I see on the screen doesnt exactly look correct though.

Comment: @JosephSanders so sir you want to update your csv in which mode?append or write?It is just returning you the df after reshaping your data  if you want to save this data in csv file then pls tell me the mode I will update the answer **:)**

Comment: Thanks! It would probably be easier to just output a new csv file named "output.csv" at location r'C:\Users\sftp\PS\IMPORTED\pythonscripts\Major-Clarity\files\'

Comment: @JosephSanders Sir updated answer..kindly have a look **:)**